# Oracle - moving objects between schemas does not work properly

Tags: oracle, create-table, privileges, sql-grant

I´ve created some tables in the schema localhost (using Oracle XE). Now I create a new user and I am trying to move the table using the command:

```
create table DIM_DOMAIN unrecoverable as select * from localhost.DIM_DOMAIN;
```

but keeps me saying that the table does not exist. If I connect as localhost the  table is there. I am not sure what I am doing wrong Can you help me guys? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to *grant select privilege* for `DIM_DOMAIN` table to your `new user` :

```
SQL> conn localhost
SQL> grant select on DIM_DOMAIN to <my_new_user>;
SQL> conn <my_new_user>
SQL> create table DIM_DOMAIN nologging as select * from localhost.DIM_DOMAIN;
-- the table will be created successfully.
```

P.s. `unrecoverable` option is deprecated, use `nologging` instead.

Comment: Same error  table or view does not exists. To the new user I already granted DBA. I am not sure if there is something with the localhost is the  SYSTEM schema  (I am very novice in oracle)

Comment: I could do it using SQL Developer

Comment: very nice friend.